# Is it possible to not send http integration request when checking structure of a JSON stringified query parameter?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have an endpoint in a AWS API Gateway project, where there is a mandatory query parameter filter.

This parameter is supposed to be a stringified JSON object. And it should contain a "where" clause, where inside of the "where" clause, there should be a "parameterB" clause.

Is there a way to avoid sending the request to HTTP integration in case that the mandatory parameters and/or the string is not a valid JSON object? (And specify an error message).

I've tried this inside the mapping template, on integration request stage:

```
#set($filterJSON = $util.parseJson($input.params('filter')))

#if(!$filterJSON)
    #set($status) = 400
    #set($errorMessage) = "Invalid JSON format for 'filter' parameter."
#else
    #set($validRequest = true)
    #if(!$util.json.contains($filterJSON, "where"))
        #set($validRequest = false)
    #elseif(!$util.json.contains($filterJSON.where, "parameterB"))
        #set($validRequest = false)
    #end
    
    #if(!$validRequest)
        #set($status) = 400
        #set($errorMessage) = "A parameterB filter should be specified inside a where clause."
    #end
#end

#if($status)
    #set($context.responseOverride.status) = $status
    #set($context.responseOverride.responseBody) = {
        "error": {
            "statusCode": $status,
            "name": "Error",
            "message": $errorMessage
        }
    }
    $util.escapeJavaScript($errorMessage)
#end
```

It generates an internal server error (500). Without trying to "prompt" an error, I can see that the logic around the validation works.

Answer (score 1):

> "Is there a way to avoid sending the request to HTTP integration in
> case that the mandatory parameters and/or the string is not a valid
> JSON object?"

Mapping template can't solve this issue, it will only transform request and always pass to the destination.

I think it's better to handle this validation at the destination, alternatively you can use custom authorizer lambda for this method.